# how to remove all css attributes and values with jquery only for defined variables?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have like this

```
var bodycss = $('body').css({'height':'0px','overflow':'hidden'}); 
bodycss; //calls bodycss 
$(selector).fadeIn('1000',function(){

}).fadeOut('5000');

bodycss.attr().remove(); // my try to remove bodycss attr and values
```

And other defaults values shouldn't be removed. I want just to remove those css which are applied by var bodycss.

---

Okay, suppose in style.css `height: 200px;` is defined but in the variable it is defined `height: 0px; overflow: hidden;` then this variables styles are only should be removed not of style.css.

Comment: check my answer demo  http://jsfiddle.net/v9M3F/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You remove them by using the empty string. For example:

```
$('#element').css('width', '');
```

In your case you could do this to delete all of them at once:

```
$("body").attr('style', '');
```

**Update**

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/v9M3F/2/

Comment: this will remove all the attribut applied anywhere in body.

Comment: again this will remove width value applied in anywhere

Comment: @NavinRauniyar that is not true. Only to the selected element.

Comment: Look at this demo I did: http://jsfiddle.net/v9M3F/2/  It works as you expect. Respecting the styles.css and delting only the style of your body, not of any other element.

Comment: Yes! But I'm still unsatisfied what I'm looking for suppose is this remove defined in jquery too. I was just searching for a solution for removing attibut style applied in variables only.

Comment: Can I ask why aren't you satisfied yet? The second code I posted, the one i added on the living example, is working as you expect, deleting the style added to the `body` with jQuery. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
var remove = [{'height':'0px'}, {'overflow':'hidden'}];

$.each(remove, function(k, v){
    $(selector).css({ k: v });
});
```

Comment: I think you are good at my solution but can you show me a fiddle please.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Are you asking about functionality to remove the css properties that are not in the css file?